# Allowing a process to use more than 4GB RAM

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ram

I am running a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on a machine with 8GB RAM. I wrote a C++ program that I compiled with the -m64 (force 64-bit executable) flag in `gcc`. I checked that the resulting executable is indeed 64-bit.

However, the process caps at using 4GB RAM. How can I allow it to use more?

Edit: output of `ulimit -a`

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited

scheduling priority             (-e) 0

file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited

pending signals                 (-i) 62900

max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64

max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

open files                      (-n) 1024

pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8

POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200

real-time priority              (-r) 0

stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192

cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

max user processes              (-u) 62900

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Edit 2: link to output of dstat -cdgms --vm

https://www.dropbox.com/s/927s5x6v4bhp4qs/dstat_log.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Look up `ulimit` and `setrlimit`.

Comment: How do you measure?

Comment: As measured by System Monitor

Comment: I looked up ulimit, updated with the output of ulimit -a. As far as I could tell, the relevant section was -d (data seg size), which is unlimited.

Comment: Where are you starting the process from? ulimit may differ for each process tree.

Comment: How do you use the RAM? What happens after 4GB? Do you get an out-of-memory exception or does `malloc` return `NULL`?

Comment: The RAM requirement is consistently at 4GB, with periodic dips followed by spikes back up. This repeated multiple times over the ~16 hours the process was running, likely when an iteration of the library function I was using finished/the next one began.My best guess is that swap memory is used, both in the long run (constantly at 2-300MB swap used), and especially between library calls (at the time of the RAM spike).

The process ran successfully, no exceptions/NULL, when I let it run alone (it got killed by the OOM killer when I had other applications running, but that is besides the point)

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I am running my executable from the command line, the output of ulimit is from the folder I am running it from. I am also calling a third party library from my code.

Comment: How much *virtual memory* does it use while RAM usage is at the 4GB mark? Does the amount grow with time? In general you should show your raw data, not just conclusions ("the process caps at using 4GB RAM" is a conclusion, a log from the System Monitor is raw data).

Comment: @n.m., I now have logs from dstat. According to these logs, the virtual memory "alloc" column peaks at seven digit numbers, with a couple of dozen of ticks in every 10000 interval. Starting at 11800, there are a few hundred of close values. The only correlation I could find between this column and the RAM used column is that the first 17 largest RAM used values have 6 digits or more in the vm alloc column. Will edit the question with a link to the file.

Comment: And where is your code? What does the program do?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I implemented a machine learning algorithm. I am expecting it to require high amounts of resources, so seeing it cap at 4GB in System Monitor / 4110M in dstat worries me, because I have more RAM available, and would like to be able to use it.

Comment: I cannot see how you derive any of your assertions from the dstat log. The system uses around 5 GiB towards the end,  almost no swap space, almost no swapping activity, no major page faults. No memory request ever fails. There is no capping of anything by anything that can be deduced from this log, nor any hint of any problem with the RAM whatsoever. It looks like you are trying to solve a non-problem.

Comment: Yeah, all we can see so far is that your system doesn't request more than that amount of memory. If you want us to help figure out why it doesn't use more, you're going to have to prove to us that it should be doing so.

Comment: Well, it turns out that I solved my initial problem (app would crash/get killed by OOM killer) by the time I wrote this question, so I ended up just confirming that my program can now run. I was skeptical at first due to swap usage, but after looking at the more detailed dstat logs, I have to agree that the program is just slow due to what it does, not because it can't access as much RAM as it needs. Debugging this taught me a few more tricks though, like using more than system monitor for logging, and things like -m64 flag and ulimit. Thank you all for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, adding the -m64 compilation flag (force 64 bit executable) actually solved my initial problem (app crashing), and what followed was a coincidence that my app actually required so little memory over 4GB (limit for a 32-bit executable) that it showed up as 4GB flat in System Monitor. Thank you to all who contributed, there are a number of things in the comments that might help people trying to diagnose similar issues.